# Data from JSF page (XHTML) is not setting into the object whose reference passed in managed bean.

Tags: java, jsf-2

```
    My XHTML:-->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`enter code here`
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/templates/mainTemplatePage.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="addProduct">


    <f:loadBundlebasename="com.erudishield.framework.propertyfile.
    ScreenConstants"
                var="constants" />
            <f:loadBundle

    basename="com.erudishield.framework.propertyfile.ScreenButtonNameConstants"
                var="buttonConstant" />
            <p:panel id="addProductPanel">

                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Add Product" />

            <!--        <h:outputLabel
                        value="#
    {addProductBB.screenDisplayData.message.screenResponseMessageForAddProduct}"
                        rendered="#
    {addProductBB.renderer.productDataRenderer.productTextRenderer}"
                        style="#  
    {productMaintenanceBB.screenDisplayData.message.screenResponseMessageColor}"
                        styleClass="outputText" escape="false">
                    </h:outputLabel>
     -->
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#
    {constant.screenDisplayData.productName}"></h:outputText>
                    <p:inputText id="addProductInput"
                        value="#{addProductBB.screenDisplayData.productName}">  
    </p:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:spacer width="415" height="20" />
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{buttonConstant.addProduct}"
                        update=":addProduct" action="#         
    {addProductBB.addProductAction}">    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

-------------------------------------------

    Managed Bean:

    package com.erudishield.erudishieldweb.bb.businessProcess;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
   import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
   import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

   import com.erudishield.erudishieldutil.validator.StringValidator;
    import com.erudishield.erudishieldweb.bb.businessProcess.bo.
    AddProductScreenDisplayData;
     import com.erudishield.erudishieldweb.bd.AddProductBD;
    import com.erudishield.erudishieldweb.bo.businessProcess.ProductRenderer;
    import com.erudishield.framework.application.constants.ApplicationConstants;
    import com.erudishield.framework.messages.MessageConstants;
    import com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.AddProductBO;
    import com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.AddProductPKBO;
    import    com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.
    AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO;
    import com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.ProductBO;
    import com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.ProductPKBO;

    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class AddProductBB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1089990299636039243L;

    private AddProductScreenDisplayData screenDisplayData;
    private ProductRenderer renderer;
    private String addProductName;
    private AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO message;

    public AddProductScreenDisplayData getScreenDisplayData() {

        return screenDisplayData;
    }

    public void setScreenDisplayData(
            AddProductScreenDisplayData screenDisplayData) {
        this.screenDisplayData = screenDisplayData;
    }

    public ProductRenderer getRenderer() {

        return renderer;
    }

    public void setRenderer(ProductRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

          AddProductScreenDisplayData screenDisplayData = new
          AddProductScreenDisplayData();
          setScreenDisplayData(screenDisplayData);
         ProductRenderer renderer = new ProductRenderer();
         setRenderer(renderer);

    }

    public void addProductAction() {
        System.out.println("Entering in method addProductAction");
    /*        initializeAllScreenMesages();
          getMessage().setScreenResponseMessageForAddProduct("");
    */       
        if (productDataValidation()) {
            getScreenDisplayData().getMessage().setScreenResponseMessageColor
    (ApplicationConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR);
        }
        else {

            AddProductBO addProductBO = convertScreenDataToAddProductBO();

            AddProductBO productBO = new AddProductBD().addProduct(
                    addProductBO, getMessage());

            if (productBO.getId() == 0) {

                commonScreenMessageRendering(
                        ApplicationConstants.ERROR_MESSAGE_COLOR,
                        getScreenDisplayData().getMessage()
                                .getScreenResponseMessageForAddProduct(),"Add");
            } else {
                commonScreenMessageRendering(
                        ApplicationConstants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE_COLOR,
                        MessageConstants.SUCCESS_PRODUCT_CREATED,"Add");
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * public void commonMessageRendering(String message, String messageColor) {
     * getScreenDisplayData().getMessage().setScreenResponseMessageColor(
     * messageColor); getScreenDisplayData().getMessage()
     * .setScreenResponseMessageForAddProduct(message);
     * 
     * }
     */

    public void commonScreenMessageRendering(String message,
            String messageColor, String action) {

        if (action.equals("Add")) {
            getScreenDisplayData().getMessage()
                    .setScreenResponseMessageForAddProduct(message);
        }
        getScreenDisplayData().getMessage().setScreenResponseMessageColor(
                messageColor);
    }

    public void initializeAllScreenMesages() {
        getScreenDisplayData().setMessage(
                new AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO());

    }

    public AddProductBO convertScreenDataToAddProductBO() {
        AddProductBO addProductBO = new AddProductBO();
        addProductBO.setProductName(getAddProductName());
        return addProductBO;
    }

    public boolean productDataValidation() {
        boolean isError = false;

        if       (StringValidator.isBlankOrNull(getScreenDisplayData().
    getProductName())) {
            //getScreenDisplayData().setProductName("");
            getScreenDisplayData().getMessage()
                    .addScreenResponseMessageForAddProductPanel(
                            MessageConstants.ERROR_PRODUCT_NAME_REQUIRED);
            isError = true;
        } else if (getAddProductName().length() >= 100) {
            //setAddProductName("");
            getScreenDisplayData().getMessage()
                    .addScreenResponseMessageForAddProductPanel(
                            MessageConstants.ERROR_LENTHIER_PRODUCT_NAME);
            isError = true;
        }
        return isError;
    }

    public String getAddProductName() {
        return addProductName;
    }

    public void setAddProductName(String addProductName) {
        this.addProductName = addProductName;
    }

    public AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    }

-------------------------------------------------------
    AddProductScreenDisplayData class

    package com.erudishield.erudishieldweb.bb.businessProcess.bo;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    import       com.erudishield.service.businessprocess.bo.
    AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO;

    public class AddProductScreenDisplayData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8033274203833911923L;

    private String productName;
    private AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO message;
    private String testScreenDisplay;

    //  private List<Object> productList;


    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(AddProductScreenResponseMessageBO message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTestScreenDisplay() {
        return testScreenDisplay;
    }

    public void setTestScreenDisplay(String testScreenDisplay) {
        this.testScreenDisplay = testScreenDisplay;
    }
    }
```

=========================================================
My question is when i am taking input from user product name and setting it to variable productName which is in AddProductScreenDisplayData object, it is setting null(It seems like it is setting null). And code breaks. I put System.out.println() statement to ensure if its entering into the addProductAction() method. Flow is entering into the method but when few validations are checked code flow breaks again. But instead of setting in AddProductScreenDisplayData if i set the product name in managed bean itself, then everything works perfectly fine. Please help me out. Where is the problem

Comment: Please correct the layout of your code. Split it up in multiple blocks. It is unreadable this way

Comment: Thanks for downvote instead of any solution. I have already resolved this question.

Comment: You are most welcome. And if you read some meta posts about downvoting, you'll see that complaining like you do and NOT doing anything with the remark I did make YESTERDAY,your chance of getting help in the future will certainly not increase. Good luck

Comment: Oh and next time if you do post code, also read about mcve in the jsf info page and [ask]

Answer (score -1):

I had to set values in BO as well as in screendisplay data to properly access the objects. It has been resolved now.

Comment: I doubt many people will understand your answer for several reasons. The most important one being the difficulty to relate it to the content of your question (due to unreadable code)